# What is the RAM capacity of a Lenovo N500 42336BU machine?

Tags: windows-7, memory, lenovo-laptop

I am running Windows 7 Professional x64 on a Lenovo N500 42336BU machine. I would like to know the maximum capacity of ram I can install on it.

Answer (score 6):

**4 GB max**, you should just paste the model number into google, the result comes right up.
But yes.. 4GB max on that unit.

Comment: What if the PC is a custom build and the End User doesn't know the Motherboard type? Your method is viable for branded computers but there are exceptions

Comment: Should I be answering a specific question for ALL possible computer types as well? your being unreasonable now...

Comment: Just pointing out that the method has flaws. That's all. Now the questions changed your answer is 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Crucial.com says the [Lenovo 3000 N500 series laptops max out at 4096 MB (4GB) of RAM](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=3000%20N500%20Series%20%28All%20Types%29)**

You can get to this page by using the pull-down menus at [Crucial.com homepage](http://Crucial.com) to select your PC's Manufacturor, Product Line, and Model.

Alternatively, their [scanner](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/index.aspx) will automatically detect your computer type and tell you which RAM slots are available for upgrade. Seems to only work with IE, though.